# Purescript Import infix type constrctor

Tags: purescript

Here, `\/` is from [Data.Either](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-either/5.0.0/docs/Data.Either.Nested).

This example is copied from the link above:

```hs
f :: (Int \/ String \/ Boolean) -> String
f = show \/ identity \/ if _ then "Yes" else "No"
```

What does the import statement look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you need to import both the type `\/` and the value `\/`.

The syntax for importing type operators is `type (\/)`. The prefix `type` is necessary for disambiguation - that is, to let the compiler know that you're importing the type, not the value that might have the same name.

And the syntax for importing the value is as usual.

So the whole import would look like this:

```
import Data.Either.Nested (type (\/), (\/))
```

In conclusion, I would recommend using your IDE integration (for example, [here's a VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nwolverson.ide-purescript)) to insert imports for you. That way you don't have to know the precise syntax.

Comment: Yup. Perfect. Though `PureScript IDE` via VSCode was all sorts of confused